# Find $ \max \{u(x,y):(x,y)\in \Omega \cup \partial \Omega\}$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Let , $\Omega=\{(x,y):x^2+(y-2)^2<4\}$ and $\partial \Omega$ be it's boundary. Consider the partial differential equation $\displaystyle \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2}=0$ in $\Omega$ and $u(x,y)=x^2-y^2$ on $\partial \Omega$. Then find $\displaystyle \max \{u(x,y):(x,y)\in \Omega \cup \partial \Omega\}$.

Please help me...